# Renomear valores no mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Tenho a seguinte consulta sql:

```
   select nf,status from notas where status = 3
```

Ao invés de trazer o número 3 no resultado da consulta sql, queria mostrar uma outra mensagem: "concluído".

como faço para renomear?

Comment: Precisa fazer um join com a tabela de status para pegar a descrição.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

se você não tiver a tabela com a descrição dos status, você pode usar o `case when`, caso contrário, utilizar o `join` com a outra tabela:

```
select 
    nf,
    status, 
    (case when status = 3 then 'Concluido' else 'Em Aberto' end) as status_descricao
from notas 
where status = 3


select 
    n.nf,
    n.status, 
    ns.descricao
from notas n
inner join notas_status ns on ns.id = n.status
where status = 3
```